# What is that missing instrument on a Beechcraft 1900C?

Tags: flight-instruments, cockpit, feature-identification, beechcraft-1900

[image]
([Full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CO7Y.jpg)) Beechcraft 1900C.

I cannot find the name of the missing instrument even in the manuals.

Answer (score 29):

Originally there was no instrument at this place, except for UE series with an electrically driven artificial horizon, where there was a fast erect pushbutton/indicator for the copilot gyro.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beechcraft_1900), UD series is for the military model and UE series is for 1900D, so I assume UC series is for 1900C model. Instrument panel for series UA/UB/UC:

[image]
<sup>Instrument panel from training manual, models UA/UB/UC ([source](https://www.scribd.com/document/158072320/Beechcraft-1900-BE1900-FS-Systems-Descriptions-Manual))</sup>

Anything visible here has been added after the aircraft left the plant, when the panel was retrofitted. When browsing pictures of this cockpit online, we can see various additions:

[image]
<sup>Sources: [Left](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Island-Air/Beech-1900C/1042241/L), [center](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Searca/Beech-1900C-1/1034994), [right](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Great-Western-Aviation-GWA/Beech-1900C/405840)</sup>

Looking at details of your image, we can see there was likely a sticker and a button associated with the instrument. This could fit with a battery temperature indicator and its test button:

[image]

<sup>Source: [Right](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B014JQZGN6)</sup>

This configuration was actually found on F-GPYY. Comparison:

[image]
<sup>Source: [Right](https://www.airteamimages.com/beechcraft-1900_F-GPYY_atlantique-air-assistance_54076.html)</sup>

Full cockpit of F-GPYY when it was an aircraft of the now defunct French Air Littoral operator:

[image]
<sup>Photo by Thierry Izzi, [source](https://www.airliners.net/photo/Air-Littoral/Beech-1900C-1/23352)</sup>

Answer (score 6):

It's a missing instrument because it's not part of the standard avionics of the 1900C model but part of the Beechcraft's 1900D aircraft avionics.

If you take a look at **pages 0 and 1 of 31-10-00-01** (chapter 31, section 10, unit 00, figure 01) of the [Beechcraft 1900D aircraft's IPC](https://ww2.txtav.com/TechnicalPublications/Downloads/Book?PN=129-590000-11) (Illustrated Parts Catalog),¹ you'll notice that the hole featured on the picture that you provided is precisely the item `100` (Part Number `101-380031-3`), which is the **Copilot's Turn and Slip Electric Indicator** (technical nomenclature `INDICATOR-COPILOT TURN AND SLIP, ELECTRIC`).

Looks like this 1900C aircraft is using a 1900D aircraft panel plate/harness but it doesn't have all the 1900D's indicators, hence the missing item `100`.

---

Footnotes:

¹ Pages 6 and 7 of the PDF file.

Comment: That’s no turn and slip indicator

Answer (score 1):

I flew the 1900D. We had 20 of them in the fleet but there wasn’t a gauge or hole there.[image]

Comment: Perhaps the difference is because 1900C and 1900D are different?

Comment: For sure they are. I was referring to Yuri’s comment about the photo looking like that 1900C using 1900D panels. Between operators there can be various differences in the avionics package, and ultimately I don’t think there’s anyway for anyone to know simply from the photo what used to be in that spot. There should be a supplement in that aircrafts technical/operating manuals that specifies what instruments/gauges would have been installed.